# Why isn't my For() Loop animation working?

Tags: p5.js

I coded a simple shooting simulator that turns your mouse to a crosshair and animates a bullet on click. I want to create an animation that enlarges the crosshair and then makes it small again when a bullet is fired. I am using a list that has the ten different sizes. This is my best attempt:

```
var imgConst = 100;
var imgSize = imgConst;
var imgChange = [4, (6 + 2/3), 10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20, (-33 - 1/3), -50];
for(var i = 0; i < imgChange.length; i++) {
  imgChange[i] = imgSize + imgConst/imgChange[i];
  imgSize = imgChange[i];
}
```

I didn't hard code numbers because I eventually want to make the crosshair dependent on window size. I used a for loop to avoid writing repetitive code. imgConst is the what size the crosshair should normally be, imgSize directly affects the crosshair, and imgChange stores the values that the animation should be. Here is my code to execute the animation:

```
for(var i = 0; i < imgChange.length * 1; i ++) {
  imgSize = imgChange[floor(i)]
}
```

The problem is that this simply does not work. I know that it goes very fast, so I decide to cap the frame rate at ten to see if it worked, and still nothing happened. As for slowing it down, I have tried making For() loops that increase by 0.1 and the size is changed to `imgChange[Math.floor(i)]` So, I guess I'm asking two questions: How do I make the animation work in the first place, and how do I slow down the animation once it's working?

Comment: Are your for loops inside of draw() ? Can you post a working snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1):

What @Charlie Wallace said; Is that for loop inside the draw function? 
When it is, it probably works. However, you loop over all the changes before drawing to the canvas, only the last change will be displayed.

You could do something like this. Every frame you update the change once. Instead of the whole range.

```
var imgConst = 100;
var imgSize = imgConst;
var imgChange = [4, (6 + 2/3), 10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -20, (-33 - 1/3), -50];
var changeIdx = 0;

function draw(){

  imgChange[ changeIdx ] = imgSize + imgConst/imgChange[ changeIdx ];
  imgSize = imgChange[ changeIdx ];

  changeIdx += 1;

}
```

Comment: No, the for() loop isn't inside the draw function. It's inside a object function.

Comment: I still think you shouldn't be looping over all the changes in 1 go. Try one change every frame, or slower.